# Android Studio automatically creating emulators

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

If I don't close the software for a long time, Android Studio will create emulators automatically, is it a bug of Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I find the cause finally, it is Genymotion, after I uninstall Genymotion, ghost emulators disappear.